# Why are the minimum distances of a code and its interleaved code equal?

Tags: channelcoding

I know this is probably a very trivial question, but I am completely stuck. Let $C$ be a linear $[n,k,d]$ Code. Then the interleaving of depth $t$ is the Code $C(t)=\{(c_{11}, \dots, c_{t1}, \dots, c_{1n}, \dots, c_{tn}) \mid (c_{i1}, \dots, c_{in}) \in C \}$. Now I am trying to understand why the minimum distance of $C(t)$ is also $d$.

As far as I understand it, $C(t)$ is also linear. Hence minimum weight equals minimum distance. But (as the weights of codewords in $C(t)$ are sums of weights of several codewords in $C$) the minimum weight of codewords in $C(t)$ is obviously larger than of those in $C$. So how can the minimum distance of $C(t)$ be $d$, as well? Any explanation would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the distance between the two interleaved codewords formed from codewords $\mathbf c_1, \mathbf c_2, \ldots, \mathbf c_t \in C$ and $\,\mathbf 0, \mathbf c_2, \ldots, \mathbf c_t \in C$ where $\mathbf c_1$ is a codeword of minimum weight $d$. The distance is $d$, no?

Answer (score 0):

You may have misunderstood "minimum distance".  It's the smallest Hamming distance of all the *pairs* of codewords in the code.   The Hamming distance is the same for any pair of codewords regardless of how you order the bits/symbols so the minimum distance of the code is unchanged.